# What should be the proper HTML element for a list item title

Tags: html, semantics

I have a list of items where each one have a title and a subtitle, something like

```html
<h2>Here's my section with some items
<ul>
  <li>
    <em>Item title</em>
    <p>Item subtitle</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em>Item title 2</em>
    <p>Item subtitle 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em>Item title 3</em>
    <p>Item subtitle 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So here's the question: what HTML element should contain item title?

Thanks!

** EDIT **:
I'm trying to figure out which HTML element is the proper HTML element for this function (being a list item title)

Comment: what do you mean? Your layout is fine, if that's how you want it to look. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Without context, there is no way to know. Even then, it's too much opinion.

Comment: The example is there: a section, with a subtitle and a list of items, which each one have its own "subtitle"... and that's the question: this subtitle should be a h3? It should be an em?

Comment: The problem, @RohanShetty is that I'm trying to give a proper semantic meaning to a <li> title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe what you looking for is the proper usage of HTML 5 Semantic Elements. Your code with ul, ol and li is fine, its to create list, but if you want to really define it as title and description (i take it as description because you write in paragraph tag), you can use dl, dt and dd [w3school explaination](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp). Here are my example.

```html
<h2>Here's my section with some items
<dl>
    <dt>Item title</dt>
    <dd>Item subtitle</dd>
    <dt>Item title 2</dt>
    <dd>Item subtitle 2</dd>
    <dt>Item title 3</dt>
    <dd>Item subtitle 3</dd>
</dl>
```

Please let me know if you have further question.

Hi Bueno !, after you gave me the example of what you trying to achieve now i can narrowed down the tag. In my perspective i will use this semantic tags :

```html
 <section>
        <header>
            <h2>Diferenciais Adentro Cloud</h2>
            <p>Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura</p>
        
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Segurança</h3>
                            <p>Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura</p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Data Center</h3>
                            <p>Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura</p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Suporte</h3>
                            <p>Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura Conheça as vantagens de ser cliente Adentro Cloud, a qualidade e atendimento diferenciado que sua empresa procura</p>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    </section>
```

Note : Bueno's example of website [website example](http://www.adentrocloud.com.br/dist/index.php), look for Diferenciais Adentro Cloud.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm trying to achieve. I mean, The `<dt> tag defines a term/name in a description list`, according to W3C... I'm not trying to define a term/name, but, for example... I have a list of products... I don't know, fruits... I have a "<em>Banana</em> <p>It's a very good yellow fruit.</p>. Do you think dt tag applies to this case?

Comment: @GabrielBueno is it for navigation or list ?, or what ?. If you can elaborate more i think i can narrowed down the tag based on your purpose and layout.

Comment: You can check this [website](http://www.adentrocloud.com.br/dist/index.php), and make a COMMAND/CTRL + F to 'Diferenciais Adentro Cloud'... they have a list with exact structure I'm aiming.

Comment: @GabrielBueno Ooh this is what you trying to achieve ?, i already open the website. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Hey @Bhimbim! Nice! I think we thought almost the same thing and this is good. Unfortunately we didn't have too much discussion about this, but I'll accept your answer! Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @GabrielBueno glad we have the same perspective. Sure !, you're welcome, glad to help :).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were going for?

```html
<h1>Here's my section with some items</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Item title</h2>
    <p>Item subtitle</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Item title 2</h2>
    <p>Item subtitle 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Item title 3</h2>
    <p>Item subtitle 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or did you want this

```html
<h2>Here's my section with some items</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <em>Item title</em>
    <p>Item subtitle</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em>Item title 2</em>
    <p>Item subtitle 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em>Item title 3</em>
    <p>Item subtitle 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Either way you forgot a closing tag for H2 it should be

Comment: I forgot a </h2>.

Comment: Actually I have a html semantics question, not a syntax question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give meaning to the titles..
First of all, add an `</h2>`.
Then use a class to give your elements a name or a group:

```
    <h2>Here's my section with some items</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <em class="itemTitle">Item title</em>
    <p>Item subtitle</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em class="itemTitle">Item title 2</em>
    <p>Item subtitle 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <em class="itemTitle">Item title 3</em>
    <p>Item subtitle 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With the class, you can then add css using

```
.itemTitle {
  /* some css code */
}
```

A class allows multiple elements to have the same grouping, whereas an id allows only a unique name (which, in some cases, is what you will need).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't make myself clear... I mean about HTML semantics... I know how to style an element, but thanks.